# multiple file vlookup in linux using awk

Tags: awk, vlookup

```
awk -f TEST.sh file1 file2 file3 file4 \> a.txt
```

the TEST.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash 

FNR==NR {a[$1];next}
$1 in a {a[$1]=a[$1] OFS "\t"$1}

END {
  for (i in a)
    print i,"\t"a[i]

}
```

And I would like to get the desired output.

[image]

How can I revise the code? thanks！

Comment: You should post the data and expected result in text format instead of an image. Also, does `file1` contain all the possible values?

Comment: Why do you have a ```\``` before the `>` in `\> a.txt`? Are you calling awk in some non-shell environment? A file that contains an awk script to be executed as `awk -f file` should not have a `#!/bin/bash` shebang.

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- `file1` contains a list of all possible id's (ie, if an id exists in any of the other files then it must also exist in `file1`)
- all files contain at least one line
- the first line of all files is `id`

Issues with current code:

- does not address what to do if `$1 in a` is false (ie, `!($1 in a)`)
- `for (i in a)` is not guaranteed to process the array indices in a particular order

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { OFS="\t" }

FNR==1  { filecnt++           }                           # filecnt used to remember order of files as they are processed
        { id = $1             }
FNR==NR { ids[++linecnt] = id }                           # linecnt used to remember order of records from first file
        { cells[filecnt,id]   }

END     { for (lineno=1; lineno<=linecnt; lineno++) {
              id = ids[lineno]
              for (fileno=1; fileno<=filecnt; fileno++)
                  printf "%s%s", ( (fileno,id) in cells ? id  : "" ), ( fileno==filecnt ? ORS : OFS )
          }
        }
' file1 file2 file3 file4 > a.txt
```

This generates:

```
$ cat a.txt
id      id      id      id
1       1       1       1
2                       2
3       3               3
4       4       4       4
5               5       5
6               6
7
8
9
10
```

---

Making a couple changes to the inputs to demonstrate maintaining the order of id's as they exist in `file1`:

```
$ cat file1
id
1
2
10
3
5
7
8
9
4
6

$ cat file4
id
3
2
5
1
4
```

The `awk` script generates:

```
$ cat a.txt
id      id      id      id
1       1       1       1
2                       2
10
3       3               3
5               5       5
7
8
9
4       4       4       4
6               6
```